# How to add a Bootstrap carousel to a Magento page?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, magento

I have created a Boostrap carousel on the homepage of my Magento site. I am having a problem with the carousel controls though.

When I enter them into the the HTML editor in the Magento homepage, the controls disappear.

This is what I enter into the content HTML editor:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"><img src="{{skin url='images/slider/2.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src={{skin url='images/slider/3.jpg'}} alt="" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src={{skin url='images/slider/4.jpg'}} alt="" /></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is what it saves as:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><!-- Indicators --><ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li class="active" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol><!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"><img src="..." alt="" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="..." alt="" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="..." alt="" /></div>
</div>
<!-- Controls --></div>
```

I've taken out the real image src's - but those get converted correctly and display the images inside a carousel on my site. But, as you can see, the controls go away.

Is there any way around this? Or **anything else** I can add to keep the controls there?

Comment: That's *not* exactly what you entered into the content HTML editor, because `<img src="..." alt="...">` is magically transformed in the output. Please share your exact code.

Comment: I've updated what was actually put into the editor above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are suffering a problem between 'show editor' and 'hide editor'.

If you are pasting HTML, ensure the editor is **hidden**.

You can see the editor changing your code if you paste the code in with the editor hidden and then show the editor and then switch back to hidden. You will see that your controls disappear.

Hide the editor, paste the HTML, save the page and leave the 'editor hidden'.

This happens because 'show/hide' really means '*switch between text editing and WYSIWYG HTML editing, and apply some HTML filtering to try to correct mistakes as you swap between the two modes*'.

Anyone who has used the visual vs text editor in WordPress will be familiar with this gotcha. And both WordPress and Magento use the TinyMCE editor (an excellent editor, HTML WYSIWYG ain't easy to code, but also I don't think either application uses the latest version).

I suspect the filtering takes place because there is no data in your anchor tag.

Comment: I knew it must be something along those lines. You were absolutely right! Thank you so much!